# Why scrollable modifier doesn't scroll view content?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

I am trying to get scrolling to work on a `Column` where the number of entries may exceed the height of the window.

I'm currently using Compose 1.1.0-rc03 and at the moment I'm only trying to get it working on desktop.

I reduced the problem to this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun App() {
    val optionsScrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        // Left column
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .scrollable(optionsScrollState, Orientation.Vertical)
                .width(240.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()
        ) {
            (1..100).forEach { i -> Text("Row $i") }
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't scroll, or at least, not with the mousewheel. Maybe there's another way to scroll that isn't immediately apparent to me.

How do I make this work?

The docs on `scrollable` say that I might have to manage the state myself. So is using `rememberScrollState()` not enough?

I found some existing questions about *disabling* scrolling on columns, but they were always talking about `LazyColumn` which I'm not using here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a wrong modifier. From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures#scrollable-modifier):

> The `scrollable` modifier differs from the scroll modifiers in that scrollable detects the scroll gestures, but does not offset its contents.

If you're interested how `Modifier.scrollable` should be used, you can find an example in the same documentation chapter.

---

You can use `Modifier.verticalScroll` instead, which will give you the expected behavior.

Also consider switching to `LazyColumn`, which already has built-in scrolling as well as lazy cell loading.

Comment: Well... I know about `LazyColumn`. But this situation is a bit quirky because I only have three cells. One cell is one row in size, the other two are expandable submenus. So the only thing I have which could potentially be lazy, is the level _under_ the tree headers, which might want to be `LazyColumn`, only I then have to manually turn scrolling _off_. :(